# Type inference engine haskell

Tags: haskell, type-inference

I am working on a project that requires me to write my own type inference engine in Haskell.

1. Why unification algorithm is important for building inference engine
2. Can I create this type inference engine with language like C#
   Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A great reference on the subject would be "Typing Haskell in Haskell" by Mark Jones. There's a [markdown version](https://gist.github.com/chrisdone/0075a16b32bfd4f62b7b) transcribed by Chris Done avaliable as well as [the original](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~mpj/thih/). Additionally, [Types and Programming Languages](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/tapl/) has an explanation of the classic Algorithm W (underlying Haskell and ML style type inference) and a proof of its correctness.

Keep in mind that type inference as a problem depends very heavily on the source language you're typing and small changes at the language level heavily impact the language. For example:

- Do you have let generalization?
- Type classes?
- A value or monomorphism restriction?
- Modules of any sort?

Answering yes or no to any of these questions will wildly alter your type inference algorithm. More information is needed in your question to be able to give you more specific resources though.

In Typing Haskell in Haskell there's also no attempt to deal with issues a real compiler might have to, like producing an annotated version of the AST so that future compilation passes know *how* something was typed, not just that it was typed. If you're building a compiler then you'll almost certainly want to do this.